# How to catch click to dial events in Unified Service Desk?

Tags: crm, microsoft-dynamics, unified-service-desk

The event raised by clicking on a phone number will either be of the form "tel:" or "skype:". Here are the steps I've followed so far to enable a window navigation rule to capture the event, and I've attached events to the rule to actually see the action get fired in the Debugger. Still, even with navigation rules set to capture tel: and skype:, the action will never fire in USD Debugger. Here is the general approach I've used so far (From another post):

1. Create a Windownavigation rule.
2. Don't put anything into the entity Settings but put "tel:" or "skype:" into the URL TextBox.
3. Routetype will be Popup
4. Target will be Tab (or registercard, at least I think that's the name for it in english - I'm using a german one)
5. Define None as Action in result for your Windownavigationrule
6. Create your own Action to resolve when the Navigation rule is triggered
7. Set your own hosted control (In this case I use the CTIConnector class.)
8. Define an Actionname for your Action that will be exectued (I named it "MakeCall" in CRM)
9. Set Data to [[SUBJECTURL]] so the URL ist given to the Action als Parameter.
10. Override the method DoAction from your hosted control

Answer (score 0):

Just 2 -3 points to verify.

1. Do you have a UII action with the name "MakeCall"? If that is there then only your code will be triggered from DoAction.
2. In case, if you have above in place please check whether your action calls and other records are added to the respective configuration reocrd?

Comment: Thanks for the response Renjith. Attached to my window navigation rule I have an action attached called "MakeCall", but no UII action titled "MakeCall". Should the standard approach be to also create a matching UII action?

Comment: Ideally what I observed is that the system picks the UII Action rather than the event. Only exception I found was for the desktop manager type of hosted control. Could you please try to add an action and then give a try. Hope that works.